# An error occurs while trying to enable Hyper-V on my computer

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, hyper-v

Good afternoon.

I want to enable Hyper-V on my home computer.

Here are the features of my computer:
[image]

As I understand, the OS on my computer is suitable for using Hyper-V.

Next, I put virtualization into BIOS and executed the following command in PowerShell as the computer administrator:
[image]

As you can see, it was completed with an error.

Next, I tried the following command in PowerShell as an administrator:
[image]

As you can see, it was also executed with an error.
Here is the part of the dism.log file that lists only errors and warnings:
[image]

Next, I found the following article on the Internet: [Hyper-V: How to Enable It and Fix Its Assembly Not Found Error](https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.731d913e-6288fa92-c9191c17-74722d776562/https/www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/hyper-v-assembly-not-found-error.html)
and then performed **the first recommended method** of correcting the error and here are its results:
[image]

Although there are no errors and executing the following command:

```
 DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

All the same, the previously described error occurs.

Then performed the **second recommended method** of correcting the error and here are its results:
[image]

Although there are no errors and executing the following command:

```
 DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

Then performed the **third recommended method** of correcting the error and here are its results:
[image]
[image]
as you can see, this method did not fix the problem either.

**Question:** How do I fix this problem?

Comment: If you can it would be helpful to post the command outputs in English. Also serverfault may be a better site to post this on.

Comment: Try to repair missing or corrupted system files. In a commandbox (as Administrator):  `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`. Then, again in commandbox as Administrator `sfc /scannow`. Both will take a long time to finish. Restart your computer and try `DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V` again